# Как обновить ListView при изменении бд

Tags: android, listview, android-fragment

Есть активити, внутри активити вкладки с фрагментами, во фрагменте - ListView,который выводит данные из бд. При нажатии на кнопку меню в активити должен обновляться ListView (кнопка очищает бд - список прямо на глазах должен очищаться). Как правильно это сделать? Пробовал через метод notifyDataSetChanged(), но пока что безрезультатно...

Answer (score 1):

Запросите заново курсор и установите заново `setAdapter` в `ListView` при нажатии на кнопку.